# Is ITR mandatory for US Visa for an Indian resident?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, paperwork, proof-of-funds

I am an Indian resident, and I will need to apply for a US visa in a while through my employer. I am not sure which visa it will be but it will be for a short duration (less than 2 months). I have filed an income tax return (ITR) for last year but not before that. I have in total 3.5 years of experience as of now and I have paid all my taxes on time.

Can I be denied Visa due to non availability of ITR for previous years? What are other important documents needed for a US visa?

Comment: I'm probably not the only one who doesn't know what **ITR** means. Is it another case of India's famous TMA?

Comment: @JoErNanO : I am both.

Comment: @hippietrail : I don't know what you are referring to by TMA, but I meant was "Income Tax Return".

Comment: Obviously everybody already knows what extremely common acronyms mean. Surely I don't have to spell out that it's "too many acronyms" when people can just Google it. Oh the effort ...

Comment: 3.5 years of experience at? Working, earning money, and paying tax? But not of filing tax returns?

Comment: @hippietrail : I am not sure how your comments help answering my question. Its quite easy to be rude but there are already enough people here for that. By the way you are an RBA.

Comment: In Stack Exchange etiquette we should try to avoid or define acronyms that many people will not know. Leaving out crucial details such as what your experience is in and why it's relevant means people will not know what you are asking and hence not know how to answer. For instance I have been to USA several times, both on a visa and on a visa waiver. I have never had to do anything in relation to income tax returns in my home country in order to visit. I have never heard the acronym ITR until this post despite being a middle-aged native English speaker.

Comment: So the point is that maybe I'm not alone in not being able to piece together what you are asking? Is work experience and income tax something needed for US work visas? Or something needed for visa applicants from developing countries? With these unknowns specified maybe more readers would be able to submit helpful answers.

Comment: I explained what I meant in just few minutes after you pointed that out, and now I see some help. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: By mentioning work experience I was only trying to say that I only had 3 chances to fill ITR out of which 1 time I did. I heard somewhere that people here were asked to carry their "Income Tax Return" document for last few years, that's the reason I asked if it was mandatory.

Comment: OK you should include those details as well. Anyway I now understand enough about your problem that I can upvote your question. I've even found other income tax questions for Schengen visas so I might make a new tag.

Comment: @pnuts: Thanks, I believe As I will be traveling on my employer's requirement, so the invitation and other document from US Division of my employer should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows all the documents that your sponsor/employee needs to submit for processing your visa:

http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/sponsor-documents.html

And here you can find the list of all documents that you will need to submit:

http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/visitor-documents.html

While your employer should be able to provide all ITR documents for the organization, it is not required for an individual.

If you are paying taxes in India, Form -16 as a proof of tax is good enough as mentioned in the visitor-documents pages.

P.S. My husband got his H1-B recently and we submitted a copy of the last year's Form 16 only. ITR-V documents were not asked from us.

Comment: I already have 11 ITR documents till date, but this year i am trying to get returns as employer or Service provider. Will it be problematic in future if i apply for H1B. My current company is not India listed and i am getting amount without any deduction  except GST for dollar conversion.